# How to swipe an image off screen with Katalon

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I am trying to select an image using katalon, and then swipe the image from right to left until a new image appears. I cant seem to find any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [command](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/mobile-swipe.html#parameters):

```
Mobile.swipe(200, 300, -100, 0)
```

Since version 5.1.0.2, the third and fourth parameter are relative x and y positions. So if the starting point of a swipe is at (200, 300) and you want to swipe left, use a negative number (-100) for the x-axis and 0 for y-axis (no vertical movement).